# No puedo acceder a los archivos de mi app desde el Andoid Device Monitor

Tags: android-studio

Si alguno sabeis que le pasa por favor decirme.

Tengo el emulador del telefono movil abierto con la app que quiero ver sus archivosd abierta.

Nada mas clicar en para abrir el android device monitor me sale esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego le doy a yes y se abre pero no me muestra nada.
Clico en mi app que quiero ver los archivos y no me muestra nada me lo muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: trata nuevamente y cuando inicie selecciona la opción "NO", comenta resultados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

Si usas un emulador, prueba levantando uno que tenga una versión anterior o igual a API 23. Al parecer ADM no muestra los archivos que se encuentran en emuladores con API superior a 23. Tal como lo mencionan [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669552/ddms-showing-empty-file-explorer-for-online-emulator).

Si usas un teléfono, los datos se deberían ver en la carpeta /data/data del proyecto. En caso de que no se muestren, prueba rooteando el teléfono.

Espero te ayude.

Comment: siii asi ya me deja ver los archivos muchas gracias @Diekrul

Comment: Me alegro que haya funcionado, puedes entonces aceptar la respuesta como correcta : )?

Comment: sii eso es darle al tick y ya no? @Diekrul esque soy nuevo en el foto jaja

Answer (score 0):

La conexión o comunicación de `Android Studio` con el dispositivo o el emulador se realiza mediante el [`ADB`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html), si lo deshabilitas, es obvio que no podrás acceder o comunicarte.

Si te pregunta `Disable ADB Integration` (desabilitar la integración con el ADB) tendrías que optar por no deshabilitarla.

Comment: si le doy a no, no se abre el android device monitor @Jorgesys

Comment: Exacto, y en el android device monitor puedes ver el File Explorer, no es así?

Comment: Cuando desabilito el ADB si pero no muestra nada y si no lo desabilito ni siquiera abre al android device monitor @Jorgesys